# Prometheus export stats from within container

Tags: prometheus

We are running our prometheus exporters in the lxc containers we want to monitor.
Unfortunately we can not run the exporter on the host and export from there as recommended with node_exporter or cAdvisor.
Installing node_exporter in the vm only reports the host system total memory and cpu usage.

Is there a exporter that I can run in a lxc container that reports the actual memory and cpu statistics of the container?
Or is this technically impossible?

Comment: Can you clarify this part "Installing node_exporter in the vm only reports the host system total memory and cpu usage."? What VM are we talking about? Why do you think that node_exporter reports the host system metrics inside VM?